# WCF (ServiceHost) is not reachable while created from outside via Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, plugins, tcp

I created a servicehost which works perfect while I'm my own runtime. Additionally I added a plugin interface that I'm able to called from outside as a plugin. while logging I can see that the servicehost is initated correctly but not reachable?!?

My ServiceHost:

```
_myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyHostClass));
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = _myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IMyHost), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:1234/MyHost");
_myHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
_myHost.Open();
```

this is working without an exception. the state is **opened**

I tried it with a http-address too but the website is not callable:

```
_myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyHostClass), new Uri("http://localhost:7777/MyHost"));
```

The Plugin-Caller from Outside:

```
Instance = (IPlugIn)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginAssembly.GetType(pluginType.ToString()))
Instance.Initialize();
```

The instance is created correctly and works

My WCF-Connector looks like that:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:1234/MyHost");
ChannelFactory<IMyHost> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyHost>(binding);
_proxy = factory.CreateChannel(address);
```

timeout because not reachable

Comment: perhaps a little more information would help. what do you mean by "outside"?